# Is there a word to (best) describe someone who sees and remembers every single thing?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Basically, as the title says. Is there a word to (best) describe someone who sees and remembers every single thing?

Comment: Do you mean a *"photographic memory"*, or do you want also want to include memory of things other than just images?

Comment: no, well generally I'm looking for a word to best describe both seeing/detecting everything and storing it. If it should be two words combine, I can live with that though... I was wondering if something like that existed...

Comment: "Photographic memory" is the common term that is well-understood.  There are no doubt psychologist's terms that no one would recognize.

Comment: Such people don't exist, so there isn't really a need for a psychology term, but they're pretty common in fiction.

Comment: Ok, I'll just come up with some kind of word of my own, thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @snailboat - Yeah, they do.

Comment: @Oldbag Then it's strange none of them will ever demonstrate their ability scientifically or choose to win money by entering the World Memory Championships, which is consistently dominated by mnemonists.  I guess they must need to keep their existence a secret! ;-)

Comment: [Herb Stempel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herb_Stempel) was/is commonly regarded to have had "photographic memory".  However, his actual skills (which were at the very least impressive) were obscured by the cheating and subsequent scandal on the *Twenty One* TV game show.  Note that the types of skills that Stempel ostensibly had were different from the ability to simply remember the order of card decks, etc (as is used in the World Memory Championships).  Stempel could read a page about a subject and then, months later, summarize that page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Eidetic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eidetic)* means

marked by or involving extraordinarily accurate and vivid recall especially of visual images; *an eidetic memory*

*Merriam-Webster*

Comment: I think that comes pretty close indeed. Thanks a lot. Have you any idea whether a word exists to best describe both seeing/detecting everything and storing it. If it should be two words combine, I can live with that though... I was wondering if something like that existed... Thinking out loud I know would say "eyedetic" ;-)...

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Marilu Henner (of "Taxi") she vividly remembers every day of her life. The phenomenon is called *Highly Superior Autobiographical Memory* - or, **H-SAM**. They had a documentary about her abilities recently.

Comment: I think I shall feel grateful for my Senior Moments henceforth......

Comment: From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthymesia), though, it doesn't sound like a hyperthymestic is exactly "someone who sees and remembers every single thing"; for example, it notes that "Hyperthymestic individuals appear to have poorer than average memory for arbitrary information" (as opposed to autobiographical information). (I guess it depends what kind of "every single thing" the OP has in mind.)

Answer (score 1):

Photographic memory would be close.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperthymesia is the *single* word meaning Highly Superior Autobiographical Memory. Hope this helps!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthymesia

Comment: I agree with Hyperthymesia, and there are people who can do this--it is a type of Asperger's syndrome.